# Why Doesn't the Viewport Optix Denoiser Doesn't Work in 2.9?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, denoise

I have the latest version of 2.9, a gtx 1060, and 16gb of ram. When I go into "denoising" and check "viewport" with "fastest (optix)" selected it'll take around 7 minutes to load the render kernels. Once it's done the viewport render freezes and gives me this error message that says.

```
OPTIX_ERROR_CUDA_ERROR in optixDenoiserComputeMemoryResources(denoiser, rect_size.x, rect_size.y, &sizes)(device_optix.cpp850)
```

I have no idea what it means and I'm mainly posting this just to see if anyone else have this problem, I don't really expect a fix for it. I've reinstalled blender, factory reset it, and updated my gpu driver to no success. Thanks for taking time to read.

Answer (score 2):

With the latest (as of this writing)  [alpha release of 2.9](https://builder.blender.org/download/) you can indeed use optix and take advantage of viewport denoising in cycles with  both CPU and certain non RTX GPUs.

From the [Cycles release notes](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.90/Cycles)

> **GPU Rendering**
>
> - OptiX support is now enabled on all NVIDIA GPUs that support it,    which is Maxwell or higher (GeForce 700, 800, 900, 1000 series).
> - NVLink support for CUDA and OptiX. When enabled in the Cycles device    preferences, GPUs connected with an NVLink bridge will share
>   memory    to support rendering bigger scenes.
> - NVIDIA GPU rendering on macOS is no longer supported. Apple dropped    support for CUDA drivers in macOS 10.14, and no recent Apple hardware
>   uses NVIDIA graphics cards.

---

> **Viewport Denoising**
>
> Intel OpenImageDenoise is now supported for interactive denoising in
> the 3D viewport. This works on any recent Intel/AMD CPU (with SSE
> 4.1).
>
> Previously viewport denoising was only supported for NVIDIA GPUs using
> OptiX.

Comment: I just installed 2.9, I have a 1060 but the optix settings in the preferences is still disabled. Do I need to install some related driver?

Comment: @TheNoob27 I would expect current drivers should work, I use a 1070 without issues in current release.

Answer (score 1):

You need a RTX class GPU to use OptiX. RTX cards include a ray trace (RT) core that this technology depends on. Sorry for the bad news :(

Edit: I am completely incorrect, disregard. Apparently Kepler+ can use OptiX.

Comment: But my friends had gotten it to work no problem on there's with the exact same specs on 2.9 because optix now supports cards that aren't an rtx

Comment: Hmmm... I did some more digging and it looks like you actually can use OptiX with older generation Nvidia cards. Here's a recent discussion with some solutions that might work for you: https://devtalk.blender.org/t/blender-2-8-cycles-optix-on-non-rtx-card/11224/41
Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, still haven't found the solution.